# How to programmatically enable visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I have created a visual studio extension and have packaged it in visual studio setup. Now, when i install the setup, the vsix gets installed and is also seen in the Extension manager window, but its in disabled state. I have tried methods like adding registry entry for the extension and etc... but same was not useful.

Answer (score -1):

You should add `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute to your package class and specify UI context when it's going to load. For auto-load vsix you should write sthm like this:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NotBuildingAndNotDebugging_string)]
public sealed class MyVSIX : Package
```